# Showing days passed in month, or total days in month if the month is over (google spreadsheets)

Tags: google-sheets

Looking for a formula (for google spreadsheets) that shows either the days past in the current month if we're not past the last day of the current month, or the total days in that month if that month is behind us.

So, if today's March 25th, the formula would output 25 ... if today's April 1st, though, the formula would output 31.

Comment: If you want to see the days past in the "current month". then the sentence " that month is behind us" don't fit to the "current month" definition anymore. you can't be in the present and the past as the same time. Are you a time traveller? 0_o

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample, this should work (assuming the date is in A1):

=if(day(A1)=1,A1-date(year(A1),month(A1)-1,1),A1-date(year(A1),month(A1),1)+1)